# why no field "event" and "arguments" at creation action in interface builder?

Tags: xcode, macos, interface-builder

my file AppDelegate.h

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

@interface AppDelegate : NSViewController <NSApplicationDelegate,NSTableViewDataSource,NSURLConnectionDataDelegate>{

NSMutableArray *users;
NSMutableArray *messages;
NSMutableData *responseData;
NSString *getUsersRequest;
NSString *getMessagesRequest;

int requestStatus;
NSInteger userId;

}

@property (weak) IBOutlet NSTableColumn *tableColumn;
@property (weak) IBOutlet NSTableView *tableUsers;
@property (weak) IBOutlet NSButton *send;
```

...

I'm trying to create action in xcode:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ItCUV.png)

but I do not see fields "event" and "arguments", Why???

Answer (score 0):

To actually create an action, you should use the `.m` (implementation) file, not your `.h` (header) file.

Also, unlike iOS, when developing for OS X and `AppKit` the options `Event` and `Arguments` are not available, this is normal.